# Merging with pandas while keeping NaNs at bottom

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge, dataframe

Let's say I have 3 dataframes, each with a single column. In each df, there are slightly more rows than in the previous one. For example:
and I want to get exactly this:

```
df1 =       col1 
        1   a
        2   b
        3   c

df2 =       col2 
        1   x
        2   y
        3   z
        4   w
        5   q

df3 =       col3 
        1   A
        2   B
        3   C
        4   D
        5   E
        6   F
        7   G
```

and I want to get exactly this:

```
res =       col1    col2    col3
        1   a       x       A
        2   b       y       B
        3   c       z       C
        4   -       w       D
        5   -       q       E
        6   -       -       F
        7   -       -       G
```

That is, I want the rows to stay in the order in which they are added, so NaNs (-) are kept in the bottom.
I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
total = pd.DataFrame()

total = pd.merge(total,df1,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
total = pd.merge(total,df2,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
total = pd.merge(total,df3,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

but I keep getting the table in a seemingly random order. Stuff like:

```
res =       col1    col2    col3
        1   a       x       A
        4   -       w       D
        3   c       z       C
        5   -       q       E
        2   b       y       B
        7   -       -       G
        6   -       -       F
```

How can I force the final df to take the desired form?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) and pass `axis=1` to do so column-wise:

```
In [203]:
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)

Out[203]:
  col1 col2 col3
1    a    x    A
2    b    y    B
3    c    z    C
4  NaN    w    D
5  NaN    q    E
6  NaN  NaN    F
7  NaN  NaN    G
```